# iOS pickerview value change based on radio button

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I want to be able to produce a certain value to a label based on a pickerview and a set of radio buttons. Is there an easier way to accomplish this for iOS than that way?  I'm going to be providing a value and have some conversion choices with the radio button.

Thanks

Comment: First: We haven't seen any code, so "efficiency" questions are futile.  Second: When asking about optimization, use [SE::CodeReview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not really a programming or a code review question, but how about two text fields each with a picker view underneath?  The text fields present quantity and the pickers select units.  Run the conversion in both directions, remembering which text field was most recently the first responder and computing the value of the other.